# How to convert jQuery code into a plugin? and plugin development patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have developed the following jQuery code.

I have some questions:

1. What is the best programming pattern to develop a jQuery plugin?
2. How do I convert my code into a plugin? (I know it is possible to do what I am asking with `$.fn.function`, but what I don't understand is how to use it with an object.)
3. Should I learn and master a single programming pattern or do I have to learn patterns, all exists?

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="linkContainer">
    <li><a href="#" class="link" data-link="one">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" data-link="two">two</a></li>

<div class="moreDetailsSection" data-section="one">
    chakabakas
</div>
<div class="moreDetailsSection" data-section="two">
    sasjakjk
</div>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
  (function ($) {


    var animation = {
        options: {
            linkContainer : $('.linkContainer'),
            section: $('.section'),
            link : $('.link'),
            mainEffect: 'slideToggle',
            mainEffectSpeed: 300
        },

        init: function (options) {                                       
            var link = this.options.link;

            $.extend(this.options, options); 
            link.on('click', this.changeWindow );
        },

        changeWindow: function () {
            var linkId = $(this).data('link'),
                options = animation.options,
                sectionContainer = animation.options.section,
                elements = sectionContainer,
                element = elements.filter('[data-section="'+ linkId +'"]');                                      
                element[options.mainEffect](options.mainEffectSpeed);                    

        }            

    }        

    animation.init();


 })(jQuery);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8bmU6/)**

Comment: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript

Comment: My personal preference is jQuery's Widget factory. Learn more here: [jQuery Widget Factory Docs](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/). Also to generate the boiler plate, [this](http://www.jqueryworkbench.com/widgetfactory.html) may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a working plugin, just have jquery interact with it.

```
$.animation = animation;
$.fn.animation = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $.animation.init($.extend({
            link: this
        }, options));
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bmU6/1/

`$.animation` is just a reference to the original plugin, and `$.fn.animation` is a wrapper so that you can call `$(".link").animation({options here})`

Answer (score 2):

I would start with [JQuery's guide to writing a plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), this will cover the basics of how to actually build a JQuery plugin. It sounds like you're more interested in learning patterns in general though, which is great! I'd start out with *how* to build a plugin and then look at how to improve the code inside it. Addy Osmani has some [great resources](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) on design patterns.

Two concepts that I try to think about when writing code are '[separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)' and the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

That's probably more than you wanted. Not all of those links are related to JQuery, but coding patterns in general. The first link should walk you through the JQuery specific parts.

Answer (score 1):

In all seriousness, have you [read the docs](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)? They're very straight-forward and `$.fn.function` is the best way to go in most cases.

This is a simple example:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    sfdsdfsdfsdf
</div>

(function($) {
    $.fn.myfunction = function() { this.html('Hi!'); }
})(jQuery);

$('#blarg').myfunction();
```

You can build in all of the support methods and objects you'll need right into the `(function($) {})(jQuery);` call.

Comment: yes. i have read it. thing is that instead of wrapping the code inside a function, what i have done is wrapping it by an object. this is where i have confused . i know this is a silly question :) thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @SameeraChathuranga you can leave your object as is and just have the plugin interact with your object (though, your init method looks a little odd... shouldn't you extend options BEFORE you define `link`?). That's typically how I build my plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to read and try to write a plugin following the **jQuery Boilerplate**
http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-oop/